# JComponent FocusListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, listener, focuslistener

I need some help with implementing a `focuslistener`. My code isn't working because no focus is registered.

Here is an image of my application:

When the user types some name in the textBox, then a list is searched for matches and the results are showed as a auto-complete textfield.

The autocomplete box that is showing up is just a simple JPanel where every name is a JPanel. I want to be able to select the specific item that has focus.

How can I do this ?

Note that I'm not allowed to use JTextField or JLabels and that's why I draw the string manually on the JPanel.

[image: Example image]

```
public class ListComponent extends JPanel{

    private List<String> l;

    public ListComponent(){
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.validate();
    }

    public void drawText(final List<String> list){

        this.removeAll();

        for(int i = 0; i<=list.size()-1; i++){
             listItem item = new listItem(list.get(i).toString()); 
             item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
             Border line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray);
             item.setBorder(line); 
             this.add(item); 
             this.validate();
        }
    }

   private class listItem extends JComponent implements FocusListener  {

       String str; 

       public listItem(String s){
           super(); 
           this.setBackground(Color.white); 
           this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
           str = s;
           this.setFocusable(true);
           this.addFocusListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g.drawString(str, 5, 15);
       }

       @Override
       public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
           System.out.println("focusGained"); 
       }

       @Override
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
           System.out.println("focusLost");
       }   
   }
}
```

Comment: `Note that I'm not allowed to use JTextField or JLabels and that's why I draw the string manually on the JPanel.` Then use a JList. It already supports selection logic.

Comment: Not allowed to use it either.

Comment: there are a few autocompleted whatever (something similair as when you added tags to question here) based on JWindow (non_editable), JDialog or JPopup, with Jlist as is suggested by @camickr, but why not using standard workaround for AutoComplete JComboBox, is there special reason for (your idea) autocomplete JTextField with suggestions or mathches displayed on separate container